# Shouldn't another accepted edit award 2 rep if you lost 2 rep due to a removed user?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I just lost 2 reputation because the user was removed. I believed that it was gained from a successful suggested edit a while back. I suggested an edit successfully again but it didn't return me the 2 reputation. I know I've suggested 500 edits but if I lose reputation because an edit got removed, shouldn't I have the chance to recover it?

Comment: Gaining rep here on this site is hard for me. I'm not a programmer that knows even 50% of the material being asked. Anyways, the linked question is not regarding the same concept. I meant can I earn it back via editing another one? Btw, the linked question is regarding votes but I was asking if I can edit a new post to get 2 rep back.

Comment: You mean you hit the reputation cap for suggested edits? I'd expect you to already have earned it. The first edit you were ever capped for would now not be capped.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and see at the bottom what your suggested edit rep total is.

Comment: > "Gaining rep here on this site is hard for me." Then do something else. Go to a hackathon. Read a book. Try a different StackExchange. "I'm not a programmer that knows even 50% of the material being asked." Programming is a huge field. Literally no one does.

Comment: No my real question here is if my suggested edit is removed shouldn't it count as 499 suggested edits gained rep off of not 500? Therefore allowing me to get 1 scored suggested edit

Comment: @puretppc: **I** don't know 50% of the material being asked. I'll be happy with the tiny corner I frequent. I won't ever beat Jon Skeet at his corner, but lucky for me he won't stand much of a chance in my corner either.

Comment: Somewhat related: a declined flag is eternal.  No statute of limitations can expunge it.

Comment: You alreaedy got 233k easily.

Comment: @puretppc: define *easily*. :-) That didn't happen overnight..

Comment: 236,663/1718 = 137.75x my rep. Also, 236,663/5 = 47333 reps per year. Me, I have 1,718/0.5 = 3436 (projected).

Comment: @puretppc Just because somebody is better than you at something doesn't mean that thing is "easy" for them. Have you considered that he's just spending more of his time here, trying harder?

Comment: How 10k answers in 5 years is *easy*?!

Comment: If you're so upset that someone is able to get more rep than you *by knowing more*, why don't you spend some time learning more relevant information/getting better at what you do instead of whining about losing 2 rep points?

Comment: Programming is hard, I don't know why we're talking about this when I just made myself a joke that rep is hard for me. 99% of the questions being asked, I could hardly understand lol

Comment: @puretppc: my first year on SO I gained [615 points](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2009-01-01/100297?sort=reputationchange#100297), the second year I gained [510 points](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2010-01-01/100297?sort=reputationchange#100297); it takes time.

Comment: Btw, I never said it was easy but I said that once you know enough programming, you'd understand pretty much most of the stuff asked no matter how long you've been around for.

Comment: I'm surprised this deserves a -6 when there was no duplicate involved with this. I smell troll votes

Comment: @puretppc: Votes mean something different on meta.  It doesn't always mean badly written or poor research, it can mean disagreement with the proposal.  (This is why meta voting doesn't affect your reputation)

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion though. And neither was it a proposal for anything. I was asking why/how I lost that rep. Ie, I felt (and still) like these votes are wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If the message says *User removed* then all you lost were *votes*, not suggested edits. The *total reputation* you earned from that user was +2. That could have been an answer upvote + 4 downvotes by that user, or 2 question upvotes, and 4 downvotes, or any other combination of voting that leaves you +2 points up, netto.

When a user is removed, all their votes are removed too as if they were never cast.

If the message states that a specific *post* was removed, then the +2 from an accepted suggested edit was reversed instead.

If you had previously hit the suggested edits cap (500 edits and +1000 reputation), then you didn't lose any reputation; your reputation will automatically be recalculated to cap *one edit later*.

The -2 message in your reputation history only notifies you that a previously earned +2 no longer exists; it is removed from your reputation history at the point it was originally added. Instead, your first suggested edit +2 rep that was ever capped will now not be capped, and you *haven't lost any net reputation*.

The reason that new suggested edits don't gain you another +2 is that you are *still capped*, just one edit later.

You can verify your total suggested edits reputation at the bottom of the https://stackoverflow.com/reputation debug view. It'll state, as the last line:

```
earned <xxxx> reputation from suggested edits
```

Wait a day to make sure recalculation has had a chance to kick in.

Comment: A suggested edit got removed. So that means I have completed and claimed points for (500-1) edits shouldn't I? I remember before that I lost 2 points when I had the rights to gain points and I was able to regain it back. But now even if ALL 500 scored edits were removed, I cannot resuggest anymore edits to get points back?

Comment: @puretppc: That's because you are back up to 1000 points for suggested edits; you regained the 2 points automatically and are *still capped*.

Comment: I had 1720 rep before the deleted one, so they knocked off 2 rep without taking another edit. That's why I'm asking this

Comment: @puretppc: what does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation say *at the bottom*? And did you wait a day yet since the message?

Comment: Nah it was recent. So you're saying that I will get back 2 rep automatically soon?

Comment: @puretppc: did you look at that link? What does the very last line say?

Comment: earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits. And it still says 1720

Comment: @puretppc: wait a day. This always happens with a rebalancing of a cap.

Comment: Nope, it's been more than 24 hours yet it didn't return me back the 2 rep. Looks like it's glitched.

Comment: Then you didn't lose the rep for a suggested edit. You lost it some other way; perhaps the user upvoted one of your answers, downvoted 4 others.

Comment: Yeah but if that was the case, wouldn't it have said -5 rep instead? THe other downvotes would've been factored in long ago right? That's why I think there's no other way besides edits this could happen

Comment: No, one answer upvote is +10, 4 downvotes is -8, so you gained a total of +2 rep. Deleting the user deletes all the votes, so you lost the net +2 again.

Comment: I don't know about that but I was never downvoted of any of my SO answers. I even checked through all answers individually and retrieved all user votes.

Comment: If the user was deleted the votes are gone too now; hard to verify after the fact.

Comment: I know that it gets deleted and the reputation was reverted but either way wouldn't I have lost 5 reputation not 2? Because the only way to gain 2 points is to suggest an edit.

Comment: Wanna help me delete this question so I can ask a more fresher question regarding this? This question seems derailed with off topic comments. I suggest getting a clean version of this would be better

Comment: I don't quite agree. Can you add the exact message to your post? If it says just *User removed* then it is invariably *votes* from the deleted user that were undone and **not** a suggested edit. The latter shows up as a deleted post instead.

Comment: On December 4, 2013, I also have a record of a deleted user. I lost 30 rep in process. So my point is, wouldn't the rep lost due to a deleted user and vote be lost in multiples of either 5 or 10?

Comment: No, absolutely not. That only happens if the user only ever upvoted you. If the user had downvoted you you'd *gain* rep in increments of 2. A combination of up and downvotes results in different amounts gained or lost. And that's not to speak of how this all interacts with the daily reputation cap.

Comment: Fine I'll have to find out on my own whether one of my questions lost an upvote but has at least 1 downvote. Btw, for deleted users, I heard there is a qualification for keeping votes. What would make a deleted user's votes stay?

Comment: See [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471); votes are retained only for very high rep users as their footprint on the site is so huge.

Comment: I know it's been a long time but your answer seems wrong. There was no way I lost only 2 rep. If the user was removed I would've lost either 5 or 10 rep. Logically there wouldn't have been any other way of earning +2 rep other than suggested edits.

Comment: Again: This is a *net* reputation change. If a user upvoted two of your questions or one answer **and** downvoted 4 of your posts, your total reputation change would have been +2 from voting by that user. When the user is deleted you lose all those votes and the *net* reputation change.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to lose two rep from a user being deleted is if the user had upvoted you.  That vote is no longer counted, and you lose the rep you received from it.

Normally an upvote awards you more than 2 rep, but there's also a daily reputation limit.  If you were near the limit when that vote was cast, it might have only been worth +2.

It's possible that you could still receive the 2 rep back, this could happen if you received another vote on the same day and received no reputation for it (because the now-deleted vote pushed you to the cap), then that vote will start counting on the next rep recalc.

Comment: I don't think I ever reached the rep cap.

Answer (score -1):

Similarly, I reached 1000 reputation without making 500 edits. Yet, I don't have a chance to receive my 500 +2's from edits since my edits don't need approval anymore.

However, there are still several ways you may recover your 2 rep:

- you can ask a question and receive an upvote
- you can answer something and receive an upvote
- you can suggest a tag wiki edit or create a tag wiki
- you can get a bounty for working on a difficult question

that really should be enough. I don't understand the mentality of being stingy with rep. The point here is to be productive in your own programming life and those of the community, so quibbling over rep in corner cases is really silly - especially when there are less silly ways to get 5x the rep back instantly.

Comment: After 2k rep, you can't suggest anymore edits for points. You can gain a total of 1k rep from editing.